# how can i direct to another mailbox and also pull xlsm file only

Tags: vba, outlook

please help, trying to change my default folder to another mailbox and also only pull csv files, based on different subject filters. below is my code. i am getting error if i use displayname to set object. and currently its pulling from my inbox. will really appreciate your assistance

```
    Public Sub Download_Attachments()

Dim OutlookOpened As Boolean
Dim outApp As Outlook.Application
Dim outNs As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim outFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim outAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
Dim outItem As Object
Dim saveFolder As String
Dim outMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim inputDate As String, subjectFilter As String, sFolderName As String
Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

saveFolder = "C:\Users\pmulei\Desktop\test" & "\" & sFolderName

subjectFilter = "Price"

displayname = "xlsm"

OutlookOpened = False
On Error Resume Next
Set outApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set outApp = New Outlook.Application
    OutlookOpened = True
End If
On Error GoTo Err_Control

If outApp Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Cannot start Outlook.", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
End If

Set outNs = outApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set outFolder = outNs.Folders.outItem("Global Real Time").Folder.outItem("Inbox")
If Not outFolder Is Nothing Then
    For Each outItem In outFolder.Items
        If outItem.Class = Outlook.OlObjectClass.olMail Then
            Set outMailItem = outItem
                If InStr(1, outMailItem.subject, subjectFilter) > 0 Then 'removed the quotes around subjectFilter
                If outMailItem.ReceivedTime >= Date Then
                    For Each outAttachment In outMailItem.Attachments
                    If Dir(saveFolder, vbDirectory) = "" Then fso.CreateFolder (saveFolder)
                If InStr(outAttachment.filename, displayname) > 0 Then
                        outAttachment.SaveAsFile saveFolder & outAttachment.filename
                    Set outAttachment = Nothing
                    Next
                    End If
                End If
        End If
        End If
    Next
End If

If OutlookOpened Then outApp.Quit
Set outApp = Nothing
Err_Control:
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox Err.Description
End If
End Suenter code here
```

Comment: Replace ``'If InStr(outAttachment, displayname) > 0 Then`` with ``If InStr(outAttachment.Filename, displayname) > 0 Then``

Comment: Thank you Elio . It worked , also wanted to know how cN i direct the query to pick on shared outlook inbox and not my inbox

Comment: Instead of  ``Set outFolder = outNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)`` use
    ``Set outFolder = outNs.Folders.Item("SharedAccountName").Folders.Item("Inbox")``.

Comment: I am getting an error of next without for and when i place the display on green as comment , i get a different error that object doesnot support this property

Comment: I don' understand what you are saying. Replace your code with the changes you made or insert a image with the code.

Comment: You didn't do what I told you! This line ``Set outFolder = outNs.Folders.outItem("Global Real Time").Folder.outItem("Inbox")`` is not correct, replace with ``Set outFolder = outNs.Folders.Item("Global Real Time").Folders.Item("Inbox")``. Try it and if any error, identify the line and paste the error description.

Comment: Set outAttachment = Nothing
                    Next - (compile error: Next without For)
                    End If

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a good practice to ident the code properly. Try to replace this part of your code.

```
Set outNs = outApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set outFolder = outNs.Folders.Item("Global Real Time").Folders.Item("Inbox")

If Not outFolder Is Nothing Then
    For Each outItem In outFolder.Items
        If outItem.Class = Outlook.OlObjectClass.olMail Then
            Set outMailItem = outItem
            If InStr(1, outMailItem.Subject, subjectFilter) > 0 Then 'removed the quotes around subjectFilter
                If outMailItem.ReceivedTime >= Date Then
                    For Each outAttachment In outMailItem.Attachments
                        If Dir(saveFolder, vbDirectory) = "" Then fso.CreateFolder (saveFolder)
                        If InStr(outAttachment.Filename, DisplayName) > 0 Then
                            outAttachment.SaveAsFile saveFolder & outAttachment.Filename
                            Set outAttachment = Nothing
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
End If
```

Comment: Thank you so much Elio it worked perfectly. Much appreciated

Comment: When the answers when they are helpful is nice to put a check on it.

Comment: thanks, i have placed a green tick.